# Xcode upgrade gives "warning: push.default is unset" when doing a git push

Tags: xcode, git

I have been using git for some time and it was working fine on my repository. However, I upgraded to XCode 7 recently and now when I try to do a `git push <branch>`, I get the following error message:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

fatal: 'Develop_New_Car' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have `git version 2.3.3`

and running `which git` gave me `/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: The real problem is in the last 4 lines. The rest is just a warning about changed default behavior.

Comment: I am able to pull without issues. And I have checked permissions, I do have the requisite permissions

Comment: `Develop_New_Car` is the name of your remote? Is the current command `git push Develop_New_Car` or `git push <remote> Develop_New_Car`?

Answer (score 0):

A `git config --global push.default simple` should be enough, but XCode7 might not be looking for the global setting in the same place ($HOME) as before.

In that case, try at least to set that config locally in the repo managed by XCode7:

```
cd /path/to/my/git/repo
git config push.default simple
```